# Git rebase from branch A to B

Tags: git

I have two branches, Master and Develop. I will like to "copy" the content of Develop in Master so:

```
Master <- Develop
```

According to documentation:

```
git rebase <base>
```

*Rebase the current branch onto base, which can be any kind of commit reference (an ID, a branch name, a tag, or a relative reference to HEAD).*

But Im not very sure about the terminology, if I check out to Master and from there i do git rebase develop am I coping everything from develop to master or the other way?

Comment: think of it like this: everything you do in git is done on your active branch -- rebase is no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git rebase X`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) means:

> move the commits of the current branch **on top of** branch `X`.

In your case:

```
git checkout Develop
git rebase master
```

But if you don't want to change the history of Develop (for instance, if Develop was already pushed to a remote repo), a simple [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) is enough.

```
git checkout master
git merge Develop
```

Comment: I usually do a Merge, but I have a conflict in one file i can figure out how to fix, i had one commit on master that is conflicting with develop, so I think doing a rebase will do the trick right?

Comment: @DomingoSL a rebase will re-apply your commits one by one, and you should still get the conflict. Do you want master to reflect the content of Develop (override)?

Comment: Im not very sure, i will like to fix the conflict so I can do the merge master<-develop, but then again I dont know how to fix it, i read that pushing the file with the conflict fix the problem but still the conflict continues.

Comment: @DomingoSL there no way around a conflict: you need to resolve it (and your merge is enough: if the Develop branch was already pushed before, a rebase isn't recommended). So: http://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/6309

Comment: I tried to follow the solutions on that post but yet no fix, mainly because im using Windows, can you please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494771/solving-conflicts-on-merge-deleted-and-modified ? Thanks!