# Solving conflicts on merge (Deleted and Modified)

Tags: git

Im trying to fix a conflict on a merge. I have to branches `Master` and `Develop`. On Develop we made the changes that after a while we merge into Master.

A while ago we had to push some modifications to `Master` since from there our server takes the code to deploy.

Of course now when we try merge Master<-Develop there is a conflict in the two files modified in Master.

So, first I tried the merge:

[image]

As you can see there is the conflict, so I tried a git status and then a git diff:

[image]

I will like to fix the problem accepting the changes made in Master.

Comment: When you have massive output from `git status` I find it easier to use `git ls-files`.  For just the unmerged files you can do `git ls-files -u` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will like to fix the problem accepting the changes made in Master.

For a specific file, using [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout --ours -- modukle/Webapp/sec/Webapp/Controller/VoucherController.php
```

Regarding the "deleted by us", if you want to keep that deletion, simply `git add -u .`.

A `git status` shouldn't show you anymore conflict.

A `git commit` is needed to complete the merge.

Comment: so:
git checkout master
git checkout --ours -- modukle/Webapp/sec/Webapp/Controller/VoucherController.php
git checkout --ours -- modukle/Webapp/sec/Webapp/Controller/TestController.php

Do I need to git reset --merge first?

Comment: @DomingoSL why git checkout master? you already are in master, if you are in the middle of a merge to master.

Comment: @DomingoSL my answer is to be applied when you are in the conflict stage of the merge.

Answer (score 0):

First rebase your branch on top of master again.

```
git rebase -i <remote_name>/master
```

Now this would result in merge conflicts **only** if the files/file you changed in your branch **Develop** are the same as the ones that were changed in **Master** in its previous commit. If not, it would simply rebase it on top of **Master**. You can then force push (`git push <remote_name> Develop --force`) to **Develop** (now that's its sync with all commits from **Master**) and create a PR.